# Where can I find online notes about statistical process control?

Tags: quality-control

Please could you someone help me to find online resources related to the topic of quality control (statistical process control)

Answer (score 4):

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control) is always a good place to start.

I've also found what appear to be a couple sets of course notes on the subject meant to serve as an introduction to statistical quality control:

- A gentle introduction to the subject that was used as a chapter for a course at the "Center for Innovation in Mathematics in Teaching" is [here](http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/alevel/fstats_ch8.pdf).
- Another pretty gentle introduction to the subject, but there appears to be much more content here with more advanced topics in the later part of the notes than in the first link. These appear to be notes used for an introductory course in Industrial Engineering and Operations Research taught by Prof. Robert C. Leachman - IEOR 130 - at the University of California at Berkeley is [here](http://www.ieor.berkeley.edu/~ieor130/SPC.pdf).
- Some nice general notes on statistical process control with `R` examples that were used as lecture notes for an Applied Statistics course taught by A. Di Bucchianico at Technische Universiteit Eindhoven in the Netherlands are [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~adibucch/2WS10/SPClecturenotes.pdf).

There are also a couple of other more application specific resources:

- [Some notes on statistical quality control in the context of optimizing software inspection](http://softwaresixsigma.com/PDFs/0301%20sqc.pdf)
- [A paper about statistical quality control in the context of clinical trials](http://www1.coe.neu.edu/~benneyan/papers/intro_spc.pdf)

These were some resources I was able to find quickly so there's probably much more out there if you search things like 'statistical quality control tutorial' or possible replacing the word 'tutorial' with 'course' or 'notes'.

Comment: Hi, Macro. This answer looks promising. Might be worth considering an edit to change "this", "this" and "these" to some form of citation; I, for one, like seeing that to have a little better sense of what to expect. (It can, of course, also help track it down in case a link ever breaks.) :-)

Comment: Thanks @cardinal, I wasn't sure what was the best way to present those links. I modified my post a bit.

Comment: (+1) Nice. I'll be interested to skim these later.

Comment: The only one I've spent any reasonable amount of time reading was the third one (A. Di Bucchianico). I think it's OK but I'm by no stretch of the imagination well versed in SPC so you may have a different impression.

Answer (score 1):

To what Macro has given you I would like to mention and give links to some textbooks that I think are very good.  Also the American Society for Quality is an organization devoted to quality and quality control and if you check out their web site I am sure you will find somwe very useful materials. ASQ Link: http://asq.org/index.aspx?WT.srch=1&WT.mc_id=MAXPPC&gclid=CHa66-jsobECFcHb4Aod-ztzfw

Books:Montgomery
[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Statistical-Quality-Editions-ebook/dp/B006QYX3CQ/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1?_encoding-UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006QYX3CQ)

Juran
[http://www.amazon.com/Jurans-Quality-Control-Handbook-Juran/dp/0070331766/ref=sr_1_11?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1342567987&si=1-11&keyword=quality+control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070331766)

and Walter Shewhart's classic that started the field

[http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Viewpoint-Quality-Control-Mathematics/dp/0486652327/ref=sr_1_28?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1342568392&si=1-28&keywords=quality+control](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486652327)

Answer (score 0):

Online resources for learning Statistical Process Control:

- The American Society for Quality is probably the best resource.  If this topic is important for your career, I would suggest getting a membership.  They have several journals and other free (to member) knowledge resources.  They also have some tools free to everyone.  You can get started on their page for [Statistical Process Control](http://asq.org/learn-about-quality/statistical-process-control/overview/overview.html).
- The National Institute of Science & Technology (NIST) has an online Engineering Statistics Handbook which is free to everyone.  They cover many topics, including [Statistical Process Control](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section1/pmc12.htm).
- iSixSigma is a website dedicated to users helping one another with topics related to the Six Sigma toolkit, including [Statistical Process Control](https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/statistical-analysis/understanding-spc/).

Other useful resources are searching via Wikipedia, google (especially google scholar), and (if you know R) to search help topics related to R.  Minitab's website may also be quite valuable to you.